# mockito getAllValues on captured arguments replaces all invocation args with the last invocation

Tags: mockito

In my code I have

```
kiteOrderService.modifyOrder(params, profitBracketOrder.getOrder().orderId);
```

and another invocation at another place. Via stepping through I have verified that the first invocation params.price is 525 and for the second it is 475. Yet in the test code

```
verify(mockKiteOrderService, times(2)).modifyOrder(orderParamsArgumentCaptor.capture(), eq("3"));
List<OrderParams> orderParamsCaptured = orderParamsArgumentCaptor.getAllValues();
assertThat(orderParamsCaptured.get(0).price).isEqualTo(525.0); 
assertThat(orderParamsCaptured.get(1).price).isEqualTo(475.0);
```

orderParamsCaptured.get(0).price is 475 and this is the value captured for both invocations.

In my build.gradle I didn't have any mockito dependency specified, I have

```
testImplementation ('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'){
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest' , module :'hamcrest-core' 
}
```

I have also tried adding

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.3.1'
```

but it didn't make any difference. I don't know which mockito version is getting used, I'm pasting my build.gradle below:

```
dependencies {
implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

implementation group: 'com.google.truth', name: 'truth', version: '1.1.3'

annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation ('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'){
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest' , module :'hamcrest-core' 
}
```

}

that may be relevant. My test is not a spring boot test but a normal Junit5 unit test has has the annotation

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You really have to show the code surrounding `modifyOrder` and how `params` is instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that creating a separate Argumentcaptor to use for each verification somehow captures the arguments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the price to your method and the price is not captured. You are passing a reference to an `OrderParams` instance. If you modify this instance later, the changes will be reflected in the captured reference. `ArgumentCaptor`s do not magically copy their captured objects, they only keep a reference to it.

Here's a simplified example:

```
final Service svc = mock(Service.class);
final Params captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Params.class);

final Params params = new Params();
params.setPrice(42);

svc.process(params);
verify(svc).process(captor.capture());

params.setPrice(1337); // this changes the captured reference!

assertEquals(1337, captor.getValue().getPrice());
```

This has nothing to do with Mockito or ArgumentCaptors, but the way Java works.

Must-read: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: But before the 2nd invocation I'm not reusing the orderParams() object and modifying it, instead I'm creating a new instance.

Comment: I found that creating a separate Argumentcaptor to use for each invocaton's verification somehow captures the arguments correctly.